# Different color classes that control the same stuff

Tags: css, sass

I have this code...

```
& .light-green {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #128465 0%, #99ca3c 100%);
    height: 100%;
    & .card__header {
        background: #128465;
        &::before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            height: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            right: 0;
            top: 100%;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            border-color: #128465 transparent transparent transparent;
        }
    }
    & .icon-icon-resolved,
    & .icon-icon-file {
        color: #128465;
    }
    & .card__actions {
        background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #128465 0%, #99ca3c 100%);
    }
}
& .dark-green {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #336666 0%, #33bc69 100%);
    height: 100%;
    & .card__header {
        background: #336666;
        &::before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            height: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            right: 0;
            top: 100%;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            border-color: #336666 transparent transparent transparent;
        }
    }
    & .icon-icon-resolved,
    & .icon-icon-file {
        color: #336666;
    }
    & .card__actions {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #336666 0%, #33bc69 100%);
    }
}
& .aqua {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #006699 0%, #33bc99 100%);
    height: 100%;
    & .card__header {
        background: #006699;
        &::before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            height: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            right: 0;
            top: 100%;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            border-color: #006699 transparent transparent transparent;
        }
    }
    & .icon-icon-resolved,
    & .icon-icon-file {
        color: #006699;
    }
    & .card__actions {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #006699 0%, #33bc99 100%);
    }
}
& .blue {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #294c95 0%, #4abed8 100%);
    height: 100%;
    & .card__header {
        background: #294c95;
        &::before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            height: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            right: 0;
            top: 100%;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            border-color: #294c95 transparent transparent transparent;
        }
    }
    & .icon-icon-resolved,
    & .icon-icon-file {
        color: #294c95;
    }
    & .card__actions {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #294c95 0%, #4abed8 100%);
    }
}

.blue-purple {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #50278f 0%, #4a8cd8 100%);
    height: 100%;
    & .card__header {
        background: #50278f;
        &::before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            height: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            right: 0;
            top: 100%;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            border-color: #50278f transparent transparent transparent;
        }
    }
    & .icon-icon-resolved,
    & .icon-icon-file {
        color: #50278f;
    }
    & .card__actions {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #50278f 0%, #4a8cd8 100%);
    }
}

.purple {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #424c9f 0%, #c16cf9 100%);
    height: 100%;
    & .card__header {
        background: #424c9f;
        &::before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            height: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            right: 0;
            top: 100%;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            border-color: #424c9f transparent transparent transparent;
        }
    }
    & .icon-icon-resolved,
    & .icon-icon-file {
        color: #424c9f;
    }
    & .card__actions {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #424c9f 0%, #c16cf9 100%);
    }
}

.purple-pink {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #522cae 0%, #be4f7e 100%);
    height: 100%;
    & .card__header {
        background: #522cae;
        &::before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            height: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            right: 0;
            top: 100%;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            border-color: #522cae transparent transparent transparent;
        }
    }
    & .icon-icon-resolved,
    & .icon-icon-file {
        color: #522cae;
    }
    & .card__actions {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #522cae 0%, #be4f7e 100%);
    }
}
.purple-orange {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ce00aa 0%, #ffa600 100%);
    height: 100%;
    & .card__header {
        background: #ce00aa;
        &::before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            height: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            right: 0;
            top: 100%;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            border-color: #ce00aa transparent transparent transparent;
        }
    }
    & .icon-icon-resolved,
    & .icon-icon-file {
        color: #ce00aa;
    }
    & .card__actions {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ce00aa 0%, #ffa600 100%);
    }
}
```

now as you can see its basically the same code the only thing that changes are the gradients and the colours.. but Im not entirely sure how I can dry this up??

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Move all your duplicate code into a class, say `gradient`.
2. Pick better names. A class name like `light-green` can mean anything, can be put on anything and really is not that great.

   I like Microsoft's (Fabric UI) method to fix this. You define your base class, say `gradient`, and then add your customizations via a subclass, say `gradient--light-green`. The double hyphen helps a lot when you come across these in the wild.
3. I don't know SASS but given my knowledge of CSS, you should be able to make a new class with all the colours removed from your class. This will be your base class. Take:

   ```
   & .gradient {
       height: 100%;
       & .card__header {
           &::before {
               content: "";
               display: inline-block;
               width: 0;
               position: absolute;
               height: 0;
               left: 0;
               margin: 0 auto;
               right: 0;
               top: 100%;
               border-style: solid;
               border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. You then just need to remove this from your other classes. Leaving something like:

   ```
   & .gradient--light-green {
       background: linear-gradient(135deg, #128465 0%, #99ca3c 100%);
       & .card__header {
           background: #128465;
           &::before {
               border-color: $color1 transparent transparent transparent;
           }
       }
       & .icon-icon-resolved,
       & .icon-icon-file {
           color: #128465;
       }
       & .card__actions {
           background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #128465 0%, #99ca3c 100%);
       }
   }
   ```
5. Notice that all of these are the same. (Except `light-green`, which has a gradient with `-45deg`, where all others have `135deg`)
6. [Learn how to use a mixin](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#defining_a_mixin), and make something like: (IDK if it works)

   ```
   @mixin gradient-colors($color1, $color2) {
       background: linear-gradient(135deg, $color1 0%, $color2 100%);
       & .card__header {
           background: $color1;
           &::before {
               border-color: $color1 transparent transparent transparent;
           }
       }
       & .icon-icon-resolved,
       & .icon-icon-file {
           color: $color1;
       }
       & .card__actions {
           background: linear-gradient(135deg, $color1 0%, $color2 100%);
       }
   }

   & .gradient--light-green {
       @include gradient-colors(#128465, #99ca3c);
   }
   ```

And so now you're left with:

```
& .gradient {
    height: 100%;
    & .card__header {
        &::before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            height: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            right: 0;
            top: 100%;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
        }
    }
}

@mixin gradient-colors($color1, $color2) {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, $color1 0%, $color2 100%);
    & .card__header {
        background: $color1;
        &::before {
            border-color: $color1 transparent transparent transparent;
        }
    }
    & .icon-icon-resolved,
    & .icon-icon-file {
        color: $color1;
    }
    & .card__actions {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, $color1 0%, $color2 100%);
    }
}

& .gradient--light-green {
    @include gradient-colors(#128465, #99ca3c);
}
& .gradient--dark-green {
    @include gradient-colors(#336666, #33bc69);
}
& .gradient--aqua {
    @include gradient-colors(#006699, #33bc99);
}
& .gradient--blue {
    @include gradient-colors(#294c95, #4abed8);
}
& .gradient--blue-purple {
    @include gradient-colors(#50278f, #4a8cd8);
}
& .gradient--purple {
    @include gradient-colors(#424c9f, #c16cf9);
}
& .gradient--purple-pink {
    @include gradient-colors(#522cae, #be4f7e);
}
& .gradient--purple-orange {
    @include gradient-colors(#ce00aa, #ffa600);
}
```